# What's a good technical way to come up with melodies in a certain scale?

Tags: scales, classical-music, melody

I'm planning on composing a piece for bassoon and flute. I want to use the whole tone scale mixed with lydian. What are some good practices to come up with melodies?

Answer (score 2):

- spend N hours noodling around on the said instruments (where N is some large positive integer). this helps ensure that the melodies are at least playable (by you, at least). (if you collect data from this you could feed a markov engine...)
- <del>steal</del> adapt from existing melodic materials (see: Stravinsky and the Rite of Spring) for example from folk sources. may run you into copyright troubles depending on what you <del>steal</del> adapt. whole tone scales notably feature in music from around the 1900s which may or may not be under the iron copyright curtain? (check with a lawyer if concerned)
- use an algorithm to generate the melody (restricted ideally to what notes the instruments can actually play). [markov chains](https://metacpan.org/pod/Music::VoiceGen) or [fractals](https://metacpan.org/pod/Music::Voss) are two among many ways of doing this. these may however be difficult to play